# find archery target in image of different perspectives

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to find a way to identify an archery target and all of its rings on a photo which might be made of different perspectives:
[image]

My goal is to identify the target and later on also where the arrows hit the target to automatically count their score. Presumptions are as follows:

- The camera's position is not fixed and might change
- The archery target might also move or rotate slightly
- The target might be of different size and have different amount of circles
- There might be many holes (sometimes big scratches) in the target

I have already tried OpenCV to find contours, but even with preprocessing (grayscale -> blur (-> threshold) -> edge detection) I still find a few houndred contours which are all distracted by the arrows or other obstacles (holes) on the target, so it is impossible to find a nice circular line. Using Hough to find circles doesn't work either as it will give me weired results as Hough will only find perfect circles and not ellipses.

With preprocessing the image this is my best result so far:

[image: preprocessed image]

I was thinking about ellipse and circle fitting, but as I don't know radius, position and pose of the target this might be a very cpu consuming task. Another thought was about using recognition from a template, but the position and rotation of the target changes often.

Now I have the idea to follow every line on the image to check if it is a curve and then guess which curves belong together to form a circle/ellipse (ellipse because of the perspective). The problem is that the lines might be intersected by arrows or holes in a short distance so the line would be too short to check if it is a curve. With the smaller circles on the target the chance is high that it isn't recognised at all. Also, as you can see, circle 8, 7 and 6 have no clear line on the left side.

I think it is not neccessary to do perspective correction to achieve this task as long as I can clearly identify all the rings in the target.

I googled a long time and found some thesis which are all not exactly focussed on this specific task and also too mathematical for me to understand.

Is it by any chance possible to achieve this task? Could you share with me an idea how to solve this problem? Anything is very appreciated.

I'm doing this in Java, but the programming language is secondary. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: are the colors fixed (without matching the exact color tone) so yellow inside, red middle, blue outside, or might this differ for different targets?

Comment: Hi Micka, there are different target papers, some don't use colors at all, just the circle lines.

Comment: very interesting task, would be nice to have some more sample images of different targets and perspectives. I guess it is not legal to assume that each circle would be a sibgle contour if there were no arrows, because some targets might have these perpendicular lines like a typical target cross?

Comment: There are a lot on google: https://www.google.de/search?q=archery+target Seeing those pictures I just figured out that it is impossible to count the arrows when 10 arrows all hit the yellow circle. Density is too high to distinguish them.

Answer (score 1):

for starters see

- [Detecting circles and shots from paper target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30423755/2521214).

If you are using standardized target as on the image ( btw. I use these same too for my bow :) ) then do not cut off the color. You can select the regions of blue red and yellow pixels to ease up the detection. see:

- [footprint fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528241/2521214)

From that you need to fit the circles. But as you got perspective then the objects are not circles nor ellipses. You got 2 options:

1. **Perspective correction**

   Use right bottom table rectangle area as marker (or the whole target). It is rectangle with known aspect ratio. so measure it on image and construct transformation that will change the image so it became rectangle again. There are tons of stuff about this: **3D scene reconstruction** so google/read/implement. The basic are based just on De-skew + scaling.
2. **Approximate circles by ellipses (not axis aligned!)**

   so fit ellipses to found edges instead circles. This will not be as precise but still close enough. see:

   - [ellipse fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36054594/2521214)

**[Edit1] sorry did not have time/mood for this for a while**

As you were unable to adapt my approach yourself here it is:

1. **remove noise**

   you need to recolor your image to remove noise to ease up the rest... I convert it to **HSV** and detect your 4 colors (circles+paper) by simple tresholding and recolor the image to 4 colors (circles,paper,background) back into **RGB** space.

   [image: result]
2. **fill the gaps**

   in some temp image I fill the gaps in circles created by arrows and stuff. It is simple just scan pixels from opposite sides of image (in each line/row) and stop if hit selected circle color (you need to go from outer circles to inner not to overwrite the previous ones...). Now just fill the space between these two points with your selected circle color. (I start with paper, then blue,red and yellow last):

   [image: result]
3. **now you can use the linked approach**

   So find avg point of each color, that is approx circle center. Then do a histogram of radius-es and chose the biggest one. From here just cast lines out of the circle and find where the circle really stops and compute the ellipse semi-axises from it and also update the center (that handles the perspective distortions). To visually check I render cross and circle for each circle into the image from **#1**:

   [image: result]

   As you can see it is pretty close. If you need even better match then cast more lines (not just 90 degree H,V lines) to obtain more points and compute ellipse algebraically or fit it by approximation (second link)

**C++ code (for explanations look into first link):**

```
picture pic0,pic1,pic2;
    // pic0 - source
    // pic1 - output
    // pic2 - temp
DWORD c0;
int x,y,i,j,n,m,r,*hist;
int x0,y0,rx,ry;    // ellipse
const int colors[4]=// color sequence from center
    {
    0x00FFFF00, // RGB yelow
    0x00FF0000, // RGB red
    0x000080FF, // RGB blue
    0x00FFFFFF, // RGB White
    };

// init output as source image and resize temp to same size
pic1=pic0;
pic2=pic0; pic2.clear(0);

// recolor image (in HSV space -> RGB) to avoid noise and select target pixels
pic1.rgb2hsv();
for (y=0;y<pic1.ys;y++)
 for (x=0;x<pic1.xs;x++)
    {
    color c;
    int h,s,v;
    c=pic1.p[y][x];
    h=c.db[picture::_h];
    s=c.db[picture::_s];
    v=c.db[picture::_v];
    if (v>100)  // bright enough pixels?
        {
        i=25; // treshold
             if (abs(h- 40)+abs(s-225)<i) c.dd=colors[0]; // RGB yelow
        else if (abs(h-250)+abs(s-165)<i) c.dd=colors[1]; // RGB red
        else if (abs(h-145)+abs(s-215)<i) c.dd=colors[2]; // RGB blue
        else if (abs(h-145)+abs(s- 10)<i) c.dd=colors[3]; // RGB white
        else                              c.dd=0x00000000; // RGB black means unselected pixels
        } else                            c.dd=0x00000000; // RGB black
    pic1.p[y][x]=c;
    }
pic1.save("out0.png");
// fit ellipses:
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Width=3;
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=0x0000FF00;
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsClear;
m=(pic1.xs+pic1.ys)*2;
hist=new int[m]; if (hist==NULL) return;
for (j=3;j>=0;j--)
    {
    // select color per pass
    c0=colors[j];
    // fill the gaps with H,V lines into temp pic2
    for (y=0;y<pic1.ys;y++)
        {
        for (x=        0;(x<pic1.xs)&&(pic1.p[y][x].dd!=c0);x++); x0=x;
        for (x=pic1.xs-1;(x>     x0)&&(pic1.p[y][x].dd!=c0);x--);
        for (;x0<x;x0++) pic2.p[y][x0].dd=c0;
        }
    for (x=0;x<pic1.xs;x++)
        {
        for (y=        0;(y<pic1.ys)&&(pic1.p[y][x].dd!=c0);y++); y0=y;
        for (y=pic1.ys-1;(y>     y0)&&(pic1.p[y][x].dd!=c0);y--);
        for (;y0<y;y0++) pic2.p[y0][x].dd=c0;
        }
    if (j==3) continue; // do not continue for border
    // avg point (possible center)
    x0=0; y0=0; n=0;
    for (y=0;y<pic2.ys;y++)
     for (x=0;x<pic2.xs;x++)
      if (pic2.p[y][x].dd==c0)
       { x0+=x; y0+=y; n++; }
    if (!n) continue;               // no points found
    x0/=n; y0/=n;                   // center
    // histogram of radius
    for (i=0;i<m;i++) hist[i]=0;
    n=0;
    for (y=0;y<pic2.ys;y++)
     for (x=0;x<pic2.xs;x++)
      if (pic2.p[y][x].dd==c0)
        {
        r=sqrt(((x-x0)*(x-x0))+((y-y0)*(y-y0))); n++;
        hist[r]++;
        }
    // select most occurent radius (biggest)
    for (r=0,i=0;i<m;i++)
     if (hist[r]<hist[i])
      r=i;
    // cast lines from possible center to find edges (and recompute rx,ry)
    for (x=x0-r,y=y0;(x>=     0)&&(pic2.p[y][x].dd==c0);x--); rx=x; // scan left
    for (x=x0+r,y=y0;(x<pic2.xs)&&(pic2.p[y][x].dd==c0);x++);       // scan right
    x0=(rx+x)>>1; rx=(x-rx)>>1;
    for (x=x0,y=y0-r;(y>=     0)&&(pic2.p[y][x].dd==c0);y--); ry=y; // scan up
    for (x=x0,y=y0+r;(y<pic2.ys)&&(pic2.p[y][x].dd==c0);y++);       // scan down
    y0=(ry+y)>>1; ry=(y-ry)>>1;

    i=10;
    pic1.bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x0-i,y0);
    pic1.bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x0+i,y0);
    pic1.bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x0,y0-i);
    pic1.bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x0,y0+i);
    //rx=r; ry=r;
    pic1.bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x0-rx,y0-ry,x0+rx,y0+ry);
    }
pic2.save("out1.png");
pic1.save("out2.png");
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Width=1;
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsSolid;
delete[] hist;
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, I tried that stuff but didn't succeed yet. I created a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691419/detect-three-nested-objects-of-similar-shape-in-an-image

Comment: @Normalo havent time for this for a while until now and it was pretty easy to implement (hard to say where you got it wrong) so I added edit1 just in case.